# How to set text on bottom of logo actionbar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9eWJ.png)

How to i print text on bottom of Action bar logo

```
<item android:title="Customer Inquiry"
    android:id="@+id/customer_inquiry"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/customer_inqury"/>
```

i set text but its not visible...!

Answer (score 0):

there is no such option for `MenuItem`, by design these items don't and shouldn't have any text. if you really need those labels you need to write own drawing class and use `app:actionLayout` or even whole custom `Toolbar` set for `Activity` with `setSupportActionBar(..)` in `Activity`